# AudioKit: How to resolve error "Use of unresolved identifier 'ABAudioSenderPort'" when integrating Audiobus?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, audiobus

At the moment, when I try to integrate Audiobus with an AudioKit iOS app I get the error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ABAudioSenderPort'

It's both the same: When I follow [the tutorial here](http://audiokit.io/audiobus/sender-synth/) or when I want to compile the AnalogSynthX-Example, I get errors. Pods are installed correctly.
Anybody? Thnx!

Comment: I gues I need to install an older version of Audiobus to make this work.

Comment: O.K. - I see: "Audiobus 3 clearly distinguishes between audio and MIDI ports. Therefore you need to rename all occurrences of ABSenderPort, ABFilterPort and ABReceiverPort to ABAudioSenderPort, ABAudioFilterPort and ABAudioReceiverPort, respectively." [#2 from https://developer.audiob.us/doc/_migration-_guide.html]

Comment: Seems like the Pod is broken. Using " pod 'Audiobus', '~> 3.0' " throws errors like Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Audiobus (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Audiobus (~> 3.0)`.

Comment: Does the project recognize 'ABSenderPort' but not recognize 'ABAudioSenderPort'? This would mean that you need a newer, not older, version of Audiobus. I had this happen when I had old Audiobus files hiding in a project I was trying to update via Pod.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant, I need newer files. But I don't get them via the pod command. It always tells me things like the upper error or (when trying "pod try Audiobus" it tells "[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down".

Comment: I just use pod 'Audiobus' and I've never had a problem.  Anyway, looking at their change log, they had a 3.0.0 but no 3.0 (currently 3.0.4) - maybe that's the problem.  But if the pod doesn't work, just download the files from the developer site and follow their directions for adding them to the project.  Worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: Yes, I did - th!nx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the newest files manually like described [here](https://developer.audiob.us/doc/_integration-_guide.html#Project-Setup)